# Certificate Generation for Python Twisted SSL

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, twisted, pki

I am trying to figure out how to setup a SSL link using the Python library Twisted.  I have managed to create a certificate that works on the server side, but I am totally stuck when it comes to the client side.

The example from the twisted [website](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/ssl.html) states:

> The following examples rely on the files server.pem (private key and
>   self-signed certificate together) and public.pem (the server’s public
>   certificate by itself).

I have generated myself a certificate and key using OpenSSL:

```
# Generate Private Key:
openssl genrsa -des3 -out certs/server.key 2048

# Generate Certificate Signing Request:
openssl req -new -key certs/server.key -sha256 -out certs/server.csr

# Generate a Self-Signed Certificate:
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in certs/server.csr -signkey certs/server.key -sha256 -out certs/server.crt

# Convert the CRT to PEM format:
openssl x509 -in certs/server.crt -out certs/server.pem -outform PEM
```

For the server-side I am combining certs/server.crt and certs/server.key to create server.pem and trying to use server.crt for public.

When I try and run my test program using:

```
certificate = ssl.PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(certData)
```

I get an error about not starting line.  Which certificate should I be using for the client if it's not server.crt please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try and run my test program using:
>
> `certificate = ssl.PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(certData)` I get an error
>   about not starting line. Which certificate should I be using for the
>   client if it's not `server.crt` please?

This should be `ssl.Certificate.LoadPEM(certData)` if you look at the example on the [Twisted howto page.](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/ssl.html)

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to have certificate based authentication for the clients as well:

I had that issue some time ago and wrote a [blog post](https://blog.keyidentity.com/2017/05/02/security-in-distributed-computing/) about my solution.
It also contains a guide to create certificates and sign them with an own certificate authority. You can find the python example code at [GitHub](https://github.com/Foxmole/twisted_tutorial).

It uses Twisted for a simple JSONRPCServer 
with certificate based authentication for both, server as well as for the clients.

The main thing is to define an own AltCtxFactory for the clients:

```
# Use our own context factory to use our certificate to authenticate
# against the server and ensure that we are using a strong SSL/TLS
# encryption method
class AltCtxFactory(ssl.ClientContextFactory):
    def getContext(self):
        # Used TLS/SSL encryption method
        sslMethod = SSL.TLSv1_2_METHOD
        # Clients private Key, used for authentication
        privKey = "<PATH TO YOUR PRIVATE KEY>"
        # Clients certificate, used for authentication
        certificate = "<PATH TO YOUR CERTIFICATE>"
        # Our trusted Certificate Authority for server connections
        accepted_ca = "<PATH TO YOUR ACCEPTED CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY>"

        self.method = sslMethod
        ctx = ssl.ClientContextFactory.getContext(self)
        # Ensure that we verify server's certificate and use our own
        # verifyCallback method to get further details of invalid certificates
        ctx.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_PEER | SSL.VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT,
                   verifyCallback)
        # Ensure that we only trust our CA
        ctx.load_verify_locations(accepted_ca)
        # Use our own Callback mehtod if a password is needed to decrypt our
        # private key
        ctx.set_passwd_cb(password_cb)
        # Use our certificate for authentication against server
        ctx.use_certificate_file(certificate)
        # Use our private key for authentication against server
        ctx.use_privatekey_file(privKey)
        return ctx
```

Feel free to use the code in your projects.

Comment: You should provide the code (or at least a good section of it) with the answer not just links.  If the link goes dead your answer becomes worthless which is why pasting the code with the answer is considered good practice. Nice blog post though.

Comment: Just like the previous comment warned about the link possibly being dead... 4 years later it appears the blogpost link is in fact dead.